# Bayesian Network (Sprinkler Example), Rain and WetGrass prediction

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

[image: Bayesian Network]

I need to find the probability of C and G. P(C and G). How can I calculate it? I got confused about how to deal with R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deal with it through DAG Factorisation and the Law of Total Probability.

The directed acyclic graph's factorisation is: $\mathsf P_{N,R,C,G} =\mathsf P_N~\mathsf P_{R\mid N}~\mathsf P_{C\mid N}~\mathsf P_{G\mid R,C}$

Then you seek: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C{=}\mathrm v,G{=}\mathrm v)&=\sum_{n\in\{\mathrm{v,f}\}}\sum_{r\in\{\mathrm{v,f}\}}\mathsf P(N{=}n,R{=}r,C{=}\mathrm v,G{=}\mathrm v)\\[2ex]&=\sum_{n\in\{\mathrm{v,f}\}}\mathsf P(N{=}n)\mathsf P(C{=}\mathrm v\mid N{=}n)\sum_{r\in\{\mathrm{v,f}\}}\mathsf P(R{=}r\mid N{=}n)\mathsf P(G{=}\mathrm v\mid C{=}\mathrm v,R{=}r)\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: Seams right, thanks! I got 0,4581 as result.